# Better way to get user feedback from Android app?

Tags: android

In my app I have an option for a user to provide feedback.

What I have is:

1) I display an activity with a list choice the items being 'satisfied', 'not satisfied', etc..

2) There's also a field 'comments' in this activity.

3) User fills the activity then I invoke a mailing app filling the mail per the data entered by user

4) User then is expected to send that mail

What happens is many users are puzzled/bored by the mail application which they think is unnecessary here, so they cancel their feedback sending half way thru.

What would be a good idea to simplify that feedback process in the application?

Comment: Is it important that it's sent via e-mail? You could setup a server to send the feedback to, whenever the user's done filling out the form. Then you wouldn't have to bother with email.

Comment: E-mail not important but I can't set up a website

Comment: why not? you can even post to some sort of google-drive-backed form probably?

Answer (score 3):

On balance, I think sending feedback by email is the best solution:

Good reasons to collect feedback via email

- your app doesn't need Internet permission
- the user can edit their reply using powerful tools, not just a text entry box
- they can attach additional information if they want
- the user can review exactly what information you are sending
- you get an email address, so can follow up when you fix the bug/ask for additional info etc

Reasons why you might want to not use email

- people are often reluctant to send the email, since that way you get to know their email address!
- since people can't edit the information, you can force it to be more constrained to whatever format you want
- if you want to be sneaky, you can piggyback additional system information in with the user provided information, without the user being aware

So if you don't use email, what are the alternatives:

1. Post data directly to a server, as mentioned in other answers
2. Open a web page form - such as a Google Spreadsheet form to collect the data indirectly

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to set up a server to collect survey results, there are many free servey sites online that will allow you to create a web survey.  You could just embed a web browser in your app and point it to a survey that you created to collect the information you want.

Answer (score 1):

As Plasma has suggested with their comment, one option is to send the data to a server.

What I have done in my owns apps, and can be easier in some cases, is to set up a website with exactly the same questions etc. as on the app. When the user then gives feedback, your app can send them to your feedback website, which would then save their responses in whatever manner you choose.

It's always good to try and keep an app contained, but I'm not sure of a better way of doing what you're suggesting apart from these two possibilities.